# How to update table column with existing value using criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-update, criteria

I am using DB2. I want to lock the table using Select for Update. But anyhow my DB is not locking the query using Select for Update. I am required to through update query on the selected row to update the same. Following will be my HQL query for the same:

```
query.append("UPDATE IfmsFundMst set finyearId = finyearId ");
Query existingQuery = this.getSession().createQuery(query.toString());
int result = existingQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Now the problem is, I want to set UPGRADE_NOWAIT lock mode using criteria. So, I am required to update the same row with existing value using criteria. Please suggest some way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

I just used setLockMode method of HQL Query itself:

```
existingQuery.setLockMode("alias", LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT);
```